# Can I import a patch without touching the working directory?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, import, patch, working-directory

Normally, Mercurial will abort if I have a dirty working copy when I try to import a patch:

```
$ hg import x.patch
abort: outstanding uncommitted changes
```

Is it possible to import it anyway?

Comment: To those who're wondering what just happened... :-) I answered the [same question on the mailinglist](http://mercurial.markmail.org/thread/pdzc5jada7exbk66) and figured that I would try "importing" the question and answer here. Compared to the mailinglist, we can reformulate things here so that we have a clear question and a clear answer. That might save us a question later. Of course it's double work to "repost" things like that and I don't really know if it's worth it.

Comment: I think it's a good idea. I've already had this problem and I think others will, since SO is well referenced on search engine, the answer will be available to a as many people as possible !

Comment: @krtek: thanks for the comment — it felt kind of weird to write and answer a question like that :-)

Comment: No need to explain yourself — “it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.” http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ (via [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions))

Comment: @LaurensHolst yeah, I know it's in the FAQ, but I've just almost never seen it done so it felt a bit weird :) Based on the positive response, I'll try to do it more in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Mercurial 1.9, you can use `hg import --bypass` to apply a patch without touching the working copy. The patch will be applied on the working copy parent revision by default. Use the `--exact` flag to apply the patch onto the changeset mentioned in the patch header instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TortoiseHg, you can use `Repository > Import`, then specify that the patch should be imported to `Shelf` and finally in the shelf, move the changes to the dirty working repository as you would with any other shelved patch.

I'd love to be able to make right click > "copy patch" in a source repository, then in a cloned repository, right click and "paste patch", hopefully this feature will be implemented in a future version.