# Can I install Mercurial in my home directory?

Tags: linux, unix, mercurial, installation, root

I would like to install Mercurial on a Linux system where I don't have `root` access.

How can I do this in a way so that I can easily uninstall Mercurial again and upgrade it when new versions are released?

Also, can I get a package for Windows that does not require admin rights to install?

Comment: It's quite odd that a core developer in the Mercurial team is asking these kinds of questions.. but yet again, this is the Internet, nothing surprises me anymore. **I'm guessing this has some SEO value to the team**, or kittens.. many kittens. Where are them kittens!?

Comment: Yeah, it feels a bit weird for me too :-) Please see the discussion we had here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521793/can-i-import-a-patch-without-touching-the-working-directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mercurial in home directory, how?

It is very easy to compile and install Mercurial in your home directory, I've done so myself.

This linked wiki-post will certainly provide some aid if you have questions;

- **[UnixInstall](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnixInstall)**

Use `make install-home` to install `hg` to your home directory, it'll put the binary file in ~/bin and associative files in ~/lib.

When uninstalling or upgrading to a new version you could either delete the files that the makefile have put in, or let `make install-home` (if upgrading) overwrite the existing files.

Make sure to update your `$PATH` after installation so that it includes `~/bin`.

---

### Install Mercurial on windows without being admin, how?

Following the link below will lead you to the download section of Mercurial. There you'll be able to find installation bundles for Windows that doesn't require administration rights.

- **[Download](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download)**

Comment: Great with the links to the wiki!

Answer (score 2):

## Linux

The [Mercurial source comes](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/tags) with a `Makefile` that has a `local` target. If you run this, then you'll build the C extensions in-place:

```
$ make local
... (lots of output) ...
python hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5b66e55c0d93+20111216)
(see https://www.mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

You will need the Python header files, they typically come in a `python-dev` package. You can then symlink the `hg` script into a directory in your `PATH`. I use `~/bin` for this:

```
$ cd ~/bin
$ ln -s ../src/mercurial/hg
```

You can now run `hg` from any directory.

If you want to uninstall Mercurial, it's as simple as deleting the directory where you did the compile. Upgrading is also easy: unpack a new release in the directory and run `make local` again. You can also use the newly install Mercurial to clone the Mercurial repository itself:

```
$ hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg
$ cd hg
$ make local
```

This gives you a version of Mercurial from the `default` branch. Use `hg update stable` before compiling if you want a build from the `stable` branch instead. That branch is only updated with bugfixes.

## Windows

On that platform, you can use a the [Inno setup installers](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads). They do not require admin rights. You can couple that with a [portable version of TortoiseHg](http://portableapps.com/node/28151) if you like.

Comment: He should probably not use `make local`, unless he's just looking for a test-session. `make install-home` seems more fitting for his needs.

Comment: Oh shiznit, I didn't notice it was OP who replied to his own question.. well "you" shouldn't use make local if you want to install it properly in your home directory.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... :-) I'm just trying out this style to see if it's helpful to people.

Comment: Wow, that was amazingly straightforward! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that this question is already answered but someone could be in the situation I was and that is to have to install without C compiler and make.

### Install without C compiler and make

Full description of the solution can be found on following [link](http://vilimpoc.org/blog/2010/10/04/installing-mercurial-without-admin-rights-and-no-c-compiler/).

List of commands, without using `make`

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg
mkdir -p ~/software/lib/python2.5/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH=~/software/lib/python2.5/site-packages
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg --prefix=~/software
export PATH=${PATH}:~/software/bin
easy_install --prefix=~/software docutils
cd ~/software
wget https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/mercurial-2.5.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf mercurial-2.5.2.tar.gz
cd mercurial-2.5.2.tar.gz
python setup.py --pure install --home="~/software" --force
cd ~/software/lib/python
mv hgext/ ../python2.5/site-packages/
mv mercurial ../python2.5/site-packages/
mv mercurial-2.5.2.egg-info ../python2.5/site-packages/
```

Append following lines to `.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/software/lib/python2.5/site-packages
export PATH=${PATH}:~/software/bin
```

Check:

```
~$ hg
Mercurial Distributed SCM
etc...
```

Comment: Let me just add that Mercurial will run slower without its C extensions.